# Can you play Nintendo Switch classic games without paying for the yearly subscription?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-eshop, nintendo-switch-online

The only way I could find out how to get classic Super Nintendo games to work on the Nintendo Switch is to sign up for Switch Online. However, I want to keep playing those games without paying for them every year.

Is it possible to purchase the classic games for Nintendo Switch? If I sign up for Switch Online and then sign out of it after a year, will I still be able to play the classic games after the subscription ends?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On an [FAQ page by Nintendo](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/41205#s1q7):

> Can I still play if I don't renew my Nintendo Switch Online membership?

> **Classic games can only be accessed by a Nintendo Account with an active Nintendo Switch Online membership.** However, the save data for the games will remain on your Nintendo Switch console and will still be available to use if you renew your membership at a later time.

It appears you are required to maintain membership in order to access these games.  I haven't been able to find any other sources indicating another way to get these classic games on Switch, so this appears to be the only way.

Comment: Worth to note - it doesn't need to be yearly. You have options with fewer months avaiable.

Answer (score 15):

No, you have to have an active subscription to play the games. You can play offline (not making connection to the internet, so no checking if your sub is cancelled), but that only last for [7 days](https://www.nintendo.com/switch/online-service/faq/).

> Can NES - Nintendo Switch Online games be played offline?
>
> Yes, these games can be played offline for up to 7 days as long as you have an active Nintendo Switch Online membership.

Answer (score 0):

Some of them are available for individual purchase as game titles in the store. Those you can pay once and use , I have like this the Donkey Kong. It costed like 5 euro to buy though. I wish Nintendo was more flexible with old IP , a good option would be to offer one classic game as a free download every xx euro spent on new  games. It would be imho better than the current points rewards that give you a discount but could coexist. Another option would be to let you for a set price (say 25 euro) pick and match a collection of oldies to get forever.